# Reference request for path integral representation of 2D Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral, ising-model

I'm looking for references that discuss the path integral approach for the two-dimensional Ising model, constructed from its transfer matrix. The only reference I know on the topic is [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/statistical-field-theory/12165C27CD62CD75E6DE2BD39CE42859), but their exposition is not much clear to me, since some details seem to be missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: David tong’s lectures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One textbook option is [*Quantum Field Theory and Condensed Matter*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521592100) by Shankar, which treats both the classical-quantum mapping and the two dimensional Ising model quite carefully. Another textbook-like option is McGreevy's [*Where do quantum field theories come from?*](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s14/239a-lectures.pdf) lecture notes, which includes this topic as one example of the classical-quantum mapping. It's also worth checking out the paper [*Order and disorder in gauge systems and magnets*](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.17.2637) by Fradkin and Susskind, which treats this mapping rather early on. Finally, John Kogut's classic review [*An introduction to lattice gauge theory and spin systems*](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.659) is a great reference for this topic, and treats the 2d Ising model fairly early on. Note that all of these references essentially cannibalize off each other (technically, from a historical perspective, Kogut's review encompasses Fradkin/Susskind's work, and Shankar/McGreevy were likely working closely along the lines of Kogut's review article), so any of these would be a good choice as a starting point.